# Querying for multiple post types in SQL

Tags: post-type, post-type-support

My site is using a plugin for displaying an archive widget. It only displays the 'post' post-type. I currently have three different post-types. Looking through the code I found:

`$where = apply_filters( 'getarchives_where', "WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_date <= now()" );`

It seemed like a easy fix. First I changed `WHERE post_type = 'post' to WHERE post_type = 'privacy, security'` but that didn't work.

Then I did `WHERE post_type => array('privacy', 'security') AND post_status = 'publish' AND post_date <= now()" );`
but that also didn't work.'

Comment: this looks like a SQL question and not a WordPress one. try with `WHERE post_type IN ('privacy', 'security') AND post_status...`

Comment: You could write your own widget or modify the `WP_Query` via `pre_get_posts` instead of upending the whole system with hacky SQL modifications? WP themes and plugins should never need to modify SQL to change what a post query fetches

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to note; one's a WordPress issue, the other an SQL issue:

For WordPress, instead of editing the plugin files directly, you should use the `'getarchives_where'` filter it provides, and change the query there.

For SQL, in order to query for multiple post types, you need a conditional statement in the query, so looking for both 'privacy' and 'security' post types <strike>requires an `OR`</strike> can be done with an `IN`.

```sql
WHERE post_type IN ('privacy', 'security') 
    AND post_status = 'publish' 
    AND post_date <= now()
```

Combine this with the plugin's filter and you get:

```php
apply_filters( 'getarchives_where', function( $where ) {
   return 'WHERE post_type IN ("privacy", "security") AND post_status = "publish" AND post_date <= now()';
    }, 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Note that using this will overwrite any other changes that plugins might have made with this filter